# Is there an app that lets me use an iPhone as a mouse?

Tags: iphone, applications, software-recommendation

I'm looking for an app which enables me to physically maneuver my iPhone on the desk to control my Mac's cursor. (I am *not* looking for a "remote trackpad" app—there are dozens of those.)

I did a great deal of searching and found nothing. Is this even possible? If so, is there an app in existence which provides this functionality?

Comment: Theoretically possible, using the accelerometer. There are several apps on the App Store which claim to do what you want, although I've never used any of them and therefore can't recommend any. Try searching for "Mouse Accelerometer" in the App Store. :)

Comment: The accelerometer and gyroscope only sense changes in position and orientation, respectively. Getting absolute position/orientation from changes in position/orientation is possible (it's called dead reckoning), but I'm doubtful that it'll yield the type of accuracy you'll need for an effective mouse. There are many trackpad-esque apps you should give a try.

Comment: Oh, and make sure you read the reviews before paying for anything -- as XAleXOwnZX says, absolute positioning is very difficult using the sensors available in an iPhone.

Comment: If you're looking for a Wiimote like app. You're going to have a bad time.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler That description implies I want to wave it around in the air. I want to slide it around on a mousepad—even just the camera could be used, fairly accurately I'd imagine.

Comment: Phone cameras aren't generally designed to focus on things ~3 mm away.  True, you don't need perfect focus, but at that range your resolution will be so exceedingly poor, why bother.  Maybe if you slid it along some glass that had a distinct pattern a few inches under it...

Comment: **absolute positioning is very difficult using the sensors available in an iPhone**  interesting idea ... use GPS to get the position of the iPhone accurately enough to serve as a mouse... :)

Comment: @NickT Obviously this is quite different, but there are apps that measure your pulse with the camera. It simply detects the changes in brightness. I'd imagine it might be possible to make this work even with the very blurry image you'd get.

Comment: @Tim it's measuring brightness as a function of time. You want to measure brightness as a function of time and two spatial dimensions. Given your brightness sensor, one might be able to measure one dimension (assuming the lighting is constant) but two dimensions is right out.

Comment: If you used all the three colors available in the camera sensor, maaaaybe, but the resolution would be useless for anything beyond a curiosity.

Answer (score 4):

To the best of my knowledge, the answer is no.  Of course, without trying out every single mouse app in the App Store, I can't be 100% certain.

I can tell you that I've been a long time user of [Mobile Mouse](http://www.mobilemouse.com).  They have about the best mouse/remote control app I've found.  They put a lot of effort into trying to get the app to work like a real mouse, and eventually decided that it couldn't be done, at least not with an acceptable level of performance (see [FAQ #6](http://www.mobilemouse.com/support.html#FAQ)).  They decided on the "air mouse" mode instead, and though it doesn't work like a real mouse, it does work very well for what it is.

Best of luck in your search, and of course if you **do** find such an app, please let us know!

Answer (score 1):

[Remote Mouse](https://itunes.apple.com/app/id385894596?mt=8) is a free app downloadable from the iOS App Store, which can act as a trackpad, "Wiimote" style controller, or keyboard.

You also have to download the [Remote Mouse Server](https://itunes.apple.com/app/remote-mouse/id403195710?mt=12) app from the Mac App Store onto the Mac you wish to control.

**This app DOES NOT work as a mouse in the traditional sense.** The closest feature to a mouse that is offered is that of a "Wiimote" style controller, where the user can wave their iPhone in the air while pointing it at the screen to move the cursor.

Comment: Please let me know in the comments if this does not work.

Comment: I have downloaded the iOS and Mac apps, and I've spent the last 15 minutes or so looking through every setting to make sure I'm not missing anything, and the nearest thing I can find is a feature which lets me wave my iPhone in the air to control it. It sounds like you're convinced it does work the way I want though; is there something I'm still missing somehow?

Comment: @timothymh I just re-downloaded the app and server and tried it out. You're absolutely correct. The app offers only a trackpad or a Wiimote/laser pointer style controller. I have updated the answer accordingly. I apologize for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Remotemouse

There is a app named remotemouse in the app store i personally have used this app so you can try it.  Its easy to use as mouse.  Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you, but this does not address my question. "I'm looking for an app which enables me to physically maneuver my iPhone on the desk to control my Mac's cursor. (I am not looking for a "remote trackpad" app—there are dozens of those.)"

Comment: @timothymh sure i am sorry for misunderstanding. If you please wait for few hours i will get back to you with best app for the purpose u want.

Comment: Okay, good luck! I've spent ages searching and so far the most promising things have all turned out to be of the waving-the-iPhone-in-the-air variety.

Answer (score 0):

Again, not what you want, but I prefer HippoRemote to the other iPhone-as-software-mouse suggestions because it doesn't require a server app to be running on your computer; you are allowed access to the computer via IP address by logging in with your user ID and you can choose to either have the app retain or erase that information. The pay version of the app also allows for specialized profiles for a variety of common apps and you can create your own profiles for others as well as create macros.

I believe that what you are looking for would require either a specialized "mouse pad" with sensors that could more accurately discern its movements or advancements in the in-iPhone motion sensors. Depending on your use case, which you have not shared with us, you might want to look into Leap Motion or some hacked together solution using a bluetooth stylus. Given that the OS X UI has been moving increasingly toward accessibility via specialized touch pad/gesture actions and with the coming increase in size of the iPhone, making it even more unwieldy to move with any precision, I find it unlikely that that effort will be made to accommodate or incorporate the features you're looking for.

Answer (score -1):

For iPhone there is Rowmote and man more (just search for Mouse) - if you find them in the iPad-AppStore they work.

Also you may take a look at AirDisplay it can make your iPad to a second Monitor but also it gives you the abillity to have a touchscreen Display.

Also you could use a VNC client to Remote Control your Mac/PC.

Comment: Thank you, but this does not address my question. "I'm looking for an app which enables me to physically maneuver my iPhone on the desk to control my Mac's cursor. (I am not looking for a "remote trackpad" app—there are dozens of those.)"

Comment: Such an App won't be very good working, sinze there is no laser nor is there a Infrared Sensor inside the iPhone. The only way i can think of would be to use the Camera to track movements. But this won't react as good as a Normal Mouse so i think no one is willing to spend 99$ a Year just to make App which probably nobody will buy. So if you really wil have such an App, you will have to program it yourself. (I wouldn't make such an App cause if one wanna move a thing to move the cursor one can use a Mouse!!!)

Answer (score -1):

I have been using [Remote Mouse](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/remote-mouse/id403195710?mt=12) (available on the App Store) for a while now.  There's no lag, no delay; It's simply amazing, it is worth checking out.

I hope it helps

Comment: What does "Remote Mouse //appstore Yang Tian Jiao" mean?

Comment: oops Yang Tian Jiao is the developer name. I added it just in case there are multiple name there. I am a newbie , I will be more specific next time. thank you for point this out.

Comment: It's better to include the link to the App Store app rather than just give the name and the author.  I fixed it for you so you could see what it should look like.  \